# Angular 2 webpack Systemjs.config.js script and css issue

Tags: angular, webpack

I want to move my angular2 application to Production,using webpack.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>iPage Quick Order</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheet.css">
  <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="src/script/systemjs.config.js"></script> 
  <script src="node_modules/ng2-bs4-modal/bundles/ng2-bs4-modal.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      System.import('src/source/app/bootstrap/main').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
  <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is that how to add css and js file to web pack
Since in prod mode I am getting error, that css and js file not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "HtmlWebpackPlugin", look at the below example:

```
    //First import this package

    import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';

    //Then add this plugin 

     plugins: [
        // Create HTML file that includes reference to bundled JS.
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: 'src/index.html',
          inject: true,
        })
      ]
```

From https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html#!#loaders website:

Webpack generates a number of js and css files. We could insert them into our index.html manually. That would be tedious and error-prone. Webpack can inject those scripts and links for us with the HtmlWebpackPlugin.